# Angular library dependency install automatically

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular-library

I have a angular library and I have that as `.tgz` file in my local. Now I want to use this library in one of my angular application. Is there a way, by which the dependency of library gets automatically installed when we run `npm install` (without adding the dependency in `package.json`).

Example:

Library depends on bootstrap, @angular/material, etc

In my project, by default I have not added any of the dependency mentioned above that library requires. I am just specifying the `"sampleLibrary": "file:./libraries/sample-library.tgz"` in package.json. If run `npm install`, I need to have all the dependency of **sampleLibrary** to get installed and available in `node_modules`.

Comment: You need to list them under the `dependencies` key in the `package.json` file of the **sampleLibrary**

Comment: Can you help me out how it works internally?

Comment: When you run `npm install`, then NPM builds the dependency tree and installs all of them. You can read about it here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list these dependencies under the `dependencies` key in the `package.json` file of the **sampleLibrary**. When you run `npm install`, NPM builds the dependency tree and installs all of the required modules. You can read more about the algorithm [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm).